# android in app payment sdk

Tags: android, mobile, payment, in-app-purchase

I want to add in app purchases to my Android app. I know I can use Google In-App Billing API, but I want to know if there are other libraries I could use that provide a more complete solution so I don't have to write as much code. I know there is Urban Airship but their fees are high. Anybody know of anything else? Are there any big names? Ideally, user would be able to pay using a variety of payment methods. Support for iOS would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Google policy differs between paying for virtual goods where you have to use Google APIs, or paying for physical goods where you can use other 3rd parties.

Also some countries are not supported by Google checkout so I guess in these countries you can use 3rd party also for virtual stuff.

This is a direct question so I will use my own company to answer
You can try ZooZ, both for Android and iOS
www.zooz.com